# KineticJS - release outside event

Tags: mouse, kineticjs

is there a way to detect if the release of the mouse is on the object itself? Something like an onReleaseOutside event in flash?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pLEru/5/ I made a little test here, I guess you already knew the result; mouseup doesn't fire when you've already left the object. I'm not sure where to go from here. Are you wanting to execute some logic when the mouse is released away from the shape?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just finding out Stack overflow, so sorry for the late reply on my side.

But yes that is excactly what i want. 

For instance, when you start dragging a bound object, and you changed the mouse cursus on the mousedown, and you are releasing it outside the bound area, so the mouse is not on the iten anymore, the cursor needs to turn back to its normal state anyway. just as it would on the mouseup function.

Comment: There are drag events in Kinetic, just like in jQuery. Have considered using those?

You can probably check if it's not on the object using if(event.target != event.source) (probably incorrect naming, but I hope you get the idea).

Comment: Thanks! I did not thought of that solution indeed :-)